# How to add multiple headers in Angular 5 HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, angular-httpclient

I'm trying to learn how to use `HttpInterceptor` to add a couple of headers to each HTTP request the app do to the API. I've got this interceptor:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()
export class fwcAPIInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const authReq = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    });

    console.log('Intercepted HTTP call', authReq);

    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}
```

Apart of the `'Content-Type'` header I need to add an `'Authorization'` but I don't how to do it (the documentation of Angular HttpHeaders is just the list of the methods, without any explanation).

How can I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

**Edit:** Following suggestions in comments I have unified both answers

**Adding more headers without overwriting** (credits to [Ketan Patil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5429123/ketan-patil) - see answer in this post)

```
const authReq = req.clone({
    headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .set('header2', 'header 2 value')
        .set('header3', 'header 3 value')
});
```

**Overwriting all headers**

```
@Injectable()
export class fwcAPIInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept (req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

  const authReq = req.clone({
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
    })
  });

  console.log('Intercepted HTTP call', authReq);

  return next.handle(authReq);
}
```

Comment: What if you have multiple interceptors? This one would overwrite those headers set before, wouldn't it?

Comment: If you have more than one interceptor for http calls you should refactor your logic: having a parent class for dealing with headers or other common logic, etc. but that's a different question not included in this one ;)

Comment: @MarcScheib check my answer.

Comment: Its not good practise to overwrite your entire headers object. Anyone looking here should check the other answers below as they have much better solutions.

Comment: to include the original headers in the `new Headers()`... you just add `...req.headers` inside. `new HttpHeaders({ ...req.headers, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })`

Comment: And how is having more than once interceptor for HTTP calls bad logic?

Answer (score 83):

Since the `set` method returns headers object every time, you can do this. This way, original headers from the intercepted request will also be retained.

```
const authReq = req.clone({
    headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .set('header2', 'header 2 value')
    .set('header3', 'header 3 value')
});
```

Comment: This is usually the way you want to do it. The accepted answer will overwrite any previous headers, so if that's what you want to do, fine; but the the OP asked to "add" headers, not reset them all.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Like stated above it will overwrite any headers already set. I was having that problem. This fixed it.

Comment: This is the right answer, it preserves existing headers.

Comment: this is great for chaining interceptor headers. a preferred approach over the accepted answer

Comment: this is the right approach as suggested by angular documentation. https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-and-updating-headers

Comment: What about `req.headers.append()` ?

Answer (score 30):

As mentioned before - accepted method overrides headers, for adding them I like approach from [API documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#set-default-headers):

```
const authReq = req.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: authToken } });
```

Comment: This really is the cleanest way to do it.

Comment: Key distinction was "set" in setHeaders

Comment: I ran into an issue where `new HttpHeaders` reset too many things. Using `setHeaders` was the better option.

Answer (score 7):

```
  const modifiedReq = req.clone({
      url: this.setUrl(req.url),
      headers: this.addExtraHeaders(req.headers)
    });
```

And the method:

```
private addExtraHeaders(headers: HttpHeaders): HttpHeaders {
  headers = headers.append('myHeader', 'abcd');
  return headers;
}
```

The method .append creates a new HttpHeaders object adds myHeader and returns the new object.

Using this solution means that you can also use multiple interceptors because you will not overwrite your headers.

Answer (score 2):

> in your interceptor file

```
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class fwcAPIInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept (req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

  const auth = req.clone({
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'Auth-Token': 'jwtToken'
    })
  });



  return next.handle(auth);
}



 **in app module**

import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CustomHttpInterceptorService, multi: true},
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Injectable()
export class fwcAPIInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers = headers.set('Authorization', 'my-auth-token');

    const authReq = req.clone({headers});
    console.log('Intercepted HTTP call', authReq);

    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I have tried following ways to send custom headers using interceptors. please check the link [stackBlitz](https://angular5-http-headers.stackblitz.io)

Please refer the console screenshot for your reference [browser console-request header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6KPz.jpg)

And the custom headers are added in

> access-control-request-headers:authkey,content-type,deviceid

I want the headers to be added as part of header, not inside access-control-request-headers. Please suggest me on this