# How to make POST Request in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

This is the below request

```
this.http.post('http://localhost:8989/anchor_web_api/resources', this.resourceMap).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

and I want to pass some parameters in header.

How to pass header request like Authorization or cross origin access control in the above post request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add multiple headers in Angular 5 HttpInterceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48683476/how-to-add-multiple-headers-in-angular-5-httpinterceptor)

Comment: cors origin manage at server side, not client side.

Comment: you need to implement the proper CORS response on the server which you’re calling,there isn't anything the client application can do about it [how to add CORS support to my server](https://enable-cors.org/server.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this,

```
    var headers = new Headers();
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     return this.http.post(
      'http://localhost:8989/anchor_web_api/resources', this.resourceMap, {
        headers: headers
      }).map(res => res)).subscribe(
        data => { console.log(data); },
        err => { console.log(err); }
      );
 }
```

Comment: How can I set the Access control to cross origin to this in header

Comment: you need to do taht in the server side or in proxy.json

Comment: where this proxy.json file resides in my angular project.?

Comment: it is not front end, back end side you need to that task

Answer (score 0):

You can use interceptors for adding Authorization tokens to your headers, Here is a link which explains how to use interceptors to write headers --> [Http Interceptors](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8) and here is Angular [Documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use authorization tokens the easiest and the correct method is to use [interceptors](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor).

You can keep your token in local storage and set it to be sent with every request:

```
localStorage.setItem('token', response.access_token);
```

Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48960671/web-tokens-in-angular-2/48962144#48962144) to see how to set token interceptor and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with instructions to [Proxy to the Backend](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md) with `proxy.conf.json`. It is normally created at the root of the Angular project structure.

```
// proxy.config.json sample
{
  "/api/": {
    "target": {
      "host": "localhost",
      "protocol": "http:",
      "port": 3000
    },
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "info"
  }
}
```

then when you're using Angular/CLI you can invoke it by:

```
ng serve  --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

Ryan Chenkie has a tech blog on [Interceptors](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8) for Angular 5, but you can create `headers` using `HttpHeaders` in your `HttpService`:

```
headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

OR

token = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`;
headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('Authorization', this.token)
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  .set('X-CustomHeader', 'custom header value')
  .set('X-CustomHeader2', 'custom header2 value')
;
```

and in your HTTP Request using `HttpClient`, add headers to the `headers` object option like so using RxJS `do` to peak into the data stream:

```
this._httpClient.post('url/to/api', { headers: this.headers })
    .do(data => console.log(data))
;
```

Or access directly in your component with the below:

```
this._httpClient.post('url/to/api', { headers: this.headers })
    .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create interceptor class to pass Authorization headers in all API. you no need to set Authorization headers for each request.

**RouteHttpInterceptor Class File**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {AuthService} from '../services/auth.service';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class RouteHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor(private auth: AuthService) {
}

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if (this.auth.token !== null) {
        return next.handle(request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.auth.token
            }
        }));
    }

    return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

**Send Params and set headers in the Post Request**

```
import {HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

const url = 'yourapi';
return this.http.post(url, {
    key: 'value',
    key1: 'value1'
},httpOptions);
```