# Is it possible to retrieve incoming http request header in Angular Application?

Tags: angular, nginx, .net-core

Is it possible to retrieve `custom header` values from incoming HTTP Requests (my angular application is called by webview on mobile app both ios and android). If it not possible in angular application is there any way to forward header to backend?

My application use `Nginx` as a web server and backend is `.NET Core` (API)

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: To inspect your request, you could use Http Interceptors. [This question has the answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48683476/how-to-add-multiple-headers-in-angular-5-httpinterceptor)