# How to set a null value for "Content-Type" header in Angular interceptor?

Tags: angular, request, interceptor, content-type, angular-http-interceptors

I have a specific request in my angular application, where I am uploading an image to the server with image details object. I am having an interceptor for a module's all api requests in the flow to append some common information for server, but for this specific request, I don't need the **Content-Type** header to be set as default to application/json.

Angular interceptor is adding application/json by default, now for file upload request, if I set:

```
"Content-Type": null
"Accept": multipart/form-data
```

The above works without interceptor when I put it in service method, so How can I modify Content-Type header and set it to null in Interceptor?

The main issue is below:

```
request.clone({body: examplebodyObject, setHeaders: { 'Content-Type': null }});
```

**null** or **undefined** is not accepted as header value in interceptor, I have also tried to delete the Content-Type header from the request, but still it does not work.

I have below code right now:

```
request = request.clone({ body: this.someFunction(request, 
otherParam), setHeaders: {
      'Accept': 'multipart/form-data'
    } });
request.headers.delete('Content-Type');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should modify the headers based on the cloned request, and pass the cloned request to next handler.

```
const clonedReq = request.clone()
clonedReq.headers.delete('Content-Type');
return next.handle(clonedReq);
```

Comment: I have mentioned in question that I tried to delete it, but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you check the request header or response header?

Comment: Request header, even after deleting Content-Type, it still adds as application/json

Comment: Could you please check it again? Request header not the response header.

Comment: yeah I am 100% sure, it is request header

Comment: Did you modify the cloned request? i just tested it ok ......

Comment: I have modified my question and posted my code, please check

Comment: Maybe you need to paste the whole file interceptor. Do you have any other interceptor which may set the Content-Type?

Comment: Yeah, this might be the case. and if it is, how can I prevent that?

Comment: Found the sequence of the interceptors to ensure last one does not contain the 'Content-Type' set. clonedReq.headers.delete should work, just debug if there is any other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution in this question [How to add multiple headers in Angular 5 HttpInterceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48683476/how-to-add-multiple-headers-in-angular-5-httpinterceptor)

Skip Content-Type like this:

```
  const newReq = req.clone({
    body: examplebodyObject,
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      Accept: 'multipart/form-data'
    })
  });
```

Comment: I tried the above, it still adds "application/json" as Content-Type in request headers